# What is the best (smallest) way to check and round off string value to nearest Int16

Tags: c#

I am trying to check and round off a string value (response.Radius) to the nearest Int16 value (radius). What is the cleanest and or most efficient way to do this? I've written the following code, and found this to be the most efficient solution. Am I correct?

There is also some additional log info which I store in the catch statement.

```
Int16 radius; Double rDouble;
            if (Double.TryParse(response.Radius, out rDouble))
            {
                var rRounded = Math.Round(rDouble);
                if (!Int16.TryParse(rRounded.ToString(), out radius))
                {
                    if (rRounded > Int16.MaxValue)
                    {
                        radius = Int16.MaxValue;
                    }
                    else if (rRounded < Int16.MinValue)
                    {
                        radius = Int16.MinValue;
                    }
                    //response.Radius = radius.ToString();
                    Logger.Info(String.Format("Received range value {0} is outside the range of SmallInt, thus it is capped to nearest value of SmallInt i.e. {2}", Int16.MaxValue, response.Radius));
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Info("Response: Range " + response.Radius + " is not a valid number");
                }
            }

return response.Radius;
```

Comment: Offtopic, fits better to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do you use `TryParse` when you throw exceptions anyways? Also, you're using exceptions to control the flow of your logic which is a bad idea.

Comment: rRounded is a decimal or double and you are passing it to Int16.TryParse(). Will that compile?

Comment: Next, what about decimal seperators? In some cultures, `"1.0"` will be parsed to `10`; so better use `double.TryParse(response.Radius, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out rDouble)`. Also, `Math.Round(1.5)` and `Math.Round(2.5)` will both produce `2.0` as a result, because bankers rounding is used. If you don't want that, you should probably use `Math.Round(rDouble, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`.

Comment: I wrote it without compiling , just change it to compilable version.

Comment: "!Int16.TryParse(rRounded.ToString(), out radius)" - that is unnecessary. You already have `rRounded` in a numeric format. No need to convert it back to a string to try parsing it to `Int16`. Just check if `rRounded` is outside `Int16.MinValue` and `Int16.MaxValue` and if not, use `(Int16)rRounded` for a faster way to get the value you want. (Converting to string and trying to parse back is slower).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the smallest and accurate code I can write.

```
Double rDouble;
if (Double.TryParse(response.Radius, out rDouble))
{
    var radius = Math.Round(Math.Min(Int16.MaxValue, Math.Max(Int16.MinValue, rDouble)));
    if (radius.ToString() != response.Radius))
    {
        Logger.Info(String.Format("Response: Received range value {0} is outside the range of SmallInt, thus it is capped to nearest value of SmallInt i.e. {1}", response.Radius, radius));
    }
    response.Radius = radius.ToString();
}
else
{
    Logger.Info("Response: Range " + response.Radius + " is not a valid number");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Jim Mischel

Comment: `response.Radius` is already a string, so using `response.Radius.ToString()` is unnecessary. And converting to string to check for equality is *bad*. What if `response.Radius` is "1.1"? That will be rounded to "1.0" and result in Int32 value of `1`. Now "1" is different from "1.1" and you'll log the wrong message. That will also happen, even if `response.Radius` is "1.0".

Comment: I've corrected the message, if value is changed in any case, I am logging message.

Comment: I wouldn't consider going from "1.0" to "1" a change, but that's for you to decide. The logged message might be a bit misleading (and won't work, because you use `{2}`, but only provide two parameters). Maybe something like: `String.Format("Response: Received value {0} was changed to {1}", response.Radius, radius)`.

Comment: And you still might want to specify an `IFormatProvider` when parsing, and probably a `MidpointRounding` mode when rounding.

Answer (score 2):

If you want smaller code, you can use `Math.Min` and `Math.Max`:

```
double d = 42793.5;

double rslt = Math.Min(Int16.MaxValue, Math.Max(Int16.MinValue, d));
```

Comment: your smallercode is perfect, but I need to convert it from string, and also log if it is out of range of smallint and then convert to nearest smallint.

Comment: @ImranRizvi: You already have code to do the conversion and range checking. My code just replaces the code that forces it in range. (that is, your two `if` statements)

Comment: Just remember that "smaller code" isn't always the best solution if it degrades the readability of the code.

Comment: @Teknikaali: You're absolutely right. That min/max thing is a common idiom for some, so for those people it actually enhances readability. But the first time you see it, you have to scratch your head. Depends on your audience, I guess. Still, you could split it into two individual calls (one to `Math.Min` and one to `Math.Max`). That would improve readability and still be shorter (and to me more readable) than the original.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the "best" way (probably not), but it should be a lot faster (by not using exceptions) and less error prone.

```
public static Int16? ToInt16(string value)
{
    double rDouble;
    if (!double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out rDouble))
    {
        // log: not a valid number
        return null;
    }
    if (rDouble < Int16.MinValue)
    {
        // log: too small
        return Int16.MinValue;
    }
    if (rDouble > Int16.MaxValue)
    {
        // log: too big
        return Int16.MaxValue;
    }

    var rounded = Math.Round(rDouble, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    return (Int16)rounded;
}
```

This method will return an [Int16?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) (Nullable< Int16 >) to be able to tell if the input was invalid or not. To work with the result, you should check if it [has a value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sksw8094.aspx) and if it does, use that [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ydkbatt6.aspx).